# AsyncTask not available in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.2. Every SDK must have AsyncTask , but my Android Studio is not able to recognize the class.Even not showing in import and autoassist.
[image]

Similarly if I write no suggestion in Autosuggest

[image]

Gradle Script:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
       compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appxperts.printknot2"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
      compile project(':libraries:floatingedittextlibrary')
      compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
      compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
      compile 'com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.5'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
     }
```

Comment: How about showing your module's gradle script?

Comment: what happens if you add `import android.os.AsyncTask;` to the import list?

Comment: Your script looks okay to me. Try what belt said you above first, if still problem persists, then do one thing: File-> Invalidate Cache/Restart-> Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.The problem was with Android Studio on Ubuntu.It is not able to automatically import AsycTask.Not even in auto-suggestions.Simply added

```
import android.os.AsyncTask
```